# How to add custom nodes and properties to AlloyUI diagram builder

Tags: javascript, node.js, alloy-ui

I have been trying to use [diagram builder example](http://alloyui.com/examples/diagram-builder/) of AlloyUI.

I need to add some extra custom node types as well as some additional properties for the nodes. I thought about modifying and then building the library but it sounds like an overkill for such a task and also I have had [issues](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/AUI-940) with building.

Is there an easy way to do this?

**UPDATE**

I realized I could directly modify files in build folder to get rid of build process. I tried adding something like:

```
var Lang = A.Lang,
..
CUSTOM = 'custom',
..

..
A.DiagramNodeCustom = A.Component.create({
  NAME: DIAGRAM_NODE_NAME,

  ATTRS: {
    type: {
      value: CUSTOM
    },
  },

  EXTENDS: A.DiagramNodeTask
});

A.DiagramBuilder.types[CUSTOM] = A.DiagramNodeCustom;
```

to `/build/aui-diagram-builder-impl/aui-diagram-builder-impl.js`.

I have my main javascript file structures as such:

```
var Y = YUI().use(
  'aui-diagram-builder',
  ..
  function(Y) {
    var availableFields = [
      ..
      {
        iconClass: 'aui-diagram-node-task-icon',
        label: 'Custom',
        type: 'custom'
      },
      ..
    ];

    diagram = new Y.DiagramBuilder(
      {
        availableFields: availableFields,
        boundingBox: '#myDiagramContainer',
        srcNode: '#myDiagramBuilder'
      }
    ).render();
    ..
  }
);
```

and I can know add a custom node to my diagram. I can click on it and change the name and such but unfortunately it is invisible on the diagram. Also I still couldn't find how to add new attributes to nodes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated, everything you did so far sounds good.

I think you're only missing some CSS to be able to see your nodes. You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/wP6PJ/)

Check out the CSS Panel

```
.aui-diagram-node-custom .aui-diagram-node-content {
   /* Style of your node in the diagram */
}

.aui-diagram-node-custom-icon {
   /* Style of your node icon in the nodes lists */
}
```

**Note:** Starting from alloy-2.0.0pr6, css classes are no longer prefixed with *aui-*, so keep that in mind when you start using a newer version. I've put together an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/wP6PJ/2/)

**Edit:** To be able to expose new attributes to the editor panel, the custom field needs to extend the `getPropertyModel` method to add the new properties to the model.

```
getPropertyModel: function() {
    var instance = this;

    var model = Y.DiagramNodeTask.superclass.getPropertyModel.apply(instance, arguments);

    model.push({
        attributeName: 'customAttr',
        name: 'Custom Attribute'
    });

    return model;
}
```

Here you can find an [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/wP6PJ/4/)

Comment: This is great, thanks. Any chance you also know how to add attributes to nodes?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that! I've updated one of the examples [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wP6PJ/4/). Basically you need to extend the `getPropertyModel` method to add the properties you want to expose.

Comment: +1, this works great for me on the front-end.  However, when I go to save the diagram I'm sending the data over by calling `builder.toJSON()`.  All of the standard attributes are there, but my custom attribute (that is displaying fine on the front-end) does not appear in the JSON object.  Any ideas?

Comment: hey @watcher in order to be printed out in the `toJSON` method, the attribute needs to be added to the `SERIALIZABLE_ATTRS` array. I've updated the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/wP6PJ/11/) so that you can check it out. Not the best code, but you should get the idea! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Everything you did sounds right. The only thing I can see is that you said you modified the file aui-**diagram-builder-impl.js**, but when creating the YUI sandbox, you're not specifying the filter to **raw** and the default YUI filter is **min**, so unless you have a global config elsewhere setting the filter to **raw**, your browser is probably loading **aui-diagram-builder-impl-min.js** instead of **aui-diagram-builder-impl.js**.

What you should do is something like:

```
YUI({ filter: 'raw' }).use(
'aui-diagram-builder',
.
.
.
)
```

But I highly recommend you to not change the build files directly. You can create your **DiagramNodeCustom** in your custom file. Just do:

```
YUI().use(
  'aui-diagram-builder',
  function(A) {
      A.DiagramNodeCustom = A.Component.create({
        NAME: DIAGRAM_NODE_NAME,

        ATTRS: {
          type: {
            value: CUSTOM
          },
        },

        EXTENDS: A.DiagramNodeTask
      });

      A.DiagramBuilder.types[CUSTOM] = A.DiagramNodeCustom;

      // and then do your thing here
  }
);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's much cleaner to define it in a custom file, thanks, but I still have the invisibility problem and don't know how to add attributes to nodes as in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tFX8H/).