# Diagram Builder Custom Attributes on Connections

Tags: javascript, alloy-ui

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431014/how-to-add-custom-nodes-and-properties-to-alloyui-diagram-builder), but it is about adding custom node types and attributes to nodes (which I have been successful in doing), and I'm looking to add custom properties on connections themselves.

I have tried overriding the methods `getProperties` and `getPropertyModel` on `builder.connector` to no avail. Below is my current (and what I believe to be closest) attempt:

```
// .. adding different node types and their attributes

var builder = new Y.DiagramBuilder( {
    availableFields: availableFields,
    boundingBox: '#diagramContainer',
    srcNode: '#diagramBuilder'
} );

builder.render();

var test = builder.connector.addAttr(
    'testAttr', 
    { 
        value:'test', 
        validator: Y.Lang.isString,
        readOnly: false,
        lazyAdd: false
    },
    false
);
builder.connector.SERIALIZABLE_ATTRS.push('testAttr');

// just calling addAttr doesn't seem to work, so I also tried this..
test.getProperties = function() {

    return [
        {
            attributeName: 'testAttr',
            editor: new Y.TextCellEditor(),
            name: 'Test Attr',
            value: 'default value??'
        }
    ]
};
```

Looking in the source, there seems to be a `STRINGS` property that may also need to be modified, but I can only find a method for getting the strings (`getStrings`) and no method for modifying them.  I could try modifying it directly, but I'm not 100% sure what object it's present on (above it is not set on the builder.connector)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sorry these things aren't as straightforward as they could be :S

I've updated the old example with a [working case](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/wP6PJ/12/) of what you're looking for. As before, not production code material, just enough to get you up and running ;)

If you look at the source code, one problem here is that the `Y.DiagramBuilderImpl` creates its own `Y.Connector` instances, so the way to go is to `mix` some extensions into it to modify the behaviour.

As you can see in the example, we create an extension with

```
var CustomConnector = function() {
};

CustomConnector.ATTRS = {
    testAttr: {
        valueFn: function() {
            return 'test attr instance value';
        }
    }
};

CustomConnector.prototype.initializer = function() {
    var instance = this;

    instance.SERIALIZABLE_ATTRS.push('testAttr');
};

CustomConnector.prototype.getPropertyModel = function() {
    var instance = this;

    return [
        {
            attributeName: 'testAttr',
            editor: new Y.TextCellEditor(),
            name: 'Test Attr'
        }
    ];
};
```

Then, we `mix` the extension into the existing `Y.Connector` adding and overriding functionality as desired with:

```
Y.Base.mix(Y.Connector, [CustomConnector]);
```

One additional option could be for you to create your own `CustomConnector` class extending `Y.Connector` (see [Base.create](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Base.html#method_create)) and then setting that as the connector class for your `DiagramBuilder` such as:

```
var builder = new Y.DiagramBuilder( {
    availableFields: availableFields,
    boundingBox: '#diagramContainer',
    connector: CustomConnector,
    srcNode: '#diagramBuilder'
});
```

Comment: Thanks again jbalsas, this works just as I need it to. I'm glad I asked the question now, because I never would have tried this :)