# AlloyUI: how to customize DiagramNode with no icons but multiple labels or attributes to be shown

Tags: svg, label, customization, diagram, alloy-ui

I am building a simple flow chart editor using AlloyUI, following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431014/how-to-add-custom-nodes-and-properties-to-alloyui-diagram-builder), and I want to customize it more, in a way that there is no icon but names and attributes can be shown together in a svg container. If there is any similar example, or any suggestions of doing this?